# As a non-student can I ask about college admissions on Academia SE?

Tags: discussion

As a non-student can I ask questions about college admissions on Academia SE, particularly regarding degree advice, registering for classes, and financial aid?

Comment: To close voters: this user doesn't have enough rep to participate in Academia's meta

Comment: @Sonic That does by no way make the question _on-topic_ here though. Pointing them to the SE Academia help center with a comment  would have been sufficient.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Where else would the user be able to ask where to ask? You could construe this as a site recommendation question, too.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't vote to close, but I did flag it for moderator attention to have it migrated. Right now it's a yes/no question and not a site recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

No. Per Academia's [help center article on what topics are accepted there](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> However, please do not ask questions about
>
> - **Undergraduate admissions**
> - Undergraduate life and culture (sports, nightlife, dorms, leaving the nest, etc.)